# Determine whether Apex transaction is asynchronous

Tags: apex, governorlimits

According to the [Execution Governors and Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm) the limits for either synchronous or asynchronous transactions can vary, that is why I would like to check whether my current apex transaction is asynchronous. Is there any way in apex to accomplish this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. The [`System`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm) class offers four methods you can call to determine if you're in Asynchronous Apex and, if so, which type:

> - `isBatch()`
>     Returns true if a batch Apex job invoked the executing code, or false if not. In API version 35.0 and earlier, also returns true if a queueable Apex job invoked the code.
> - `isFuture()`
>     Returns true if the currently executing code is invoked by code contained in a method annotated with future; false otherwise.
> - `isQueueable()`
>     Returns true if a queueable Apex job invoked the executing code. Returns false if not, including if a batch Apex job or a future method invoked the code.
> - `isScheduled()`
>     Returns true if the currently executing code is invoked by a scheduled Apex job; false otherwise.

Comment: I only wish we had something like `System.isAsynchronous()` to wrap all four of those into a nice tidy bundle.

Comment: I'd created the idea to [expose the "Quiddity" as an enum](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003XnHQAU). The motivation being that it would help in scenarios where you care about the execution context/type.

Comment: Don't forget the mother of all contexts that can have expanded limits: Email services ;-)

Answer (score 2):

How about something like below?

```
public static Boolean isAsynchronous(){
    return (Limits.getLimitCpuTime() == 60000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer that mentions the four methods on the System class is slightly misleading.

As strange as it may seem, scheduled Apex in regards to Limits is considered a "synchronous" context, while the other three mentioned (future, queueable, batch) are truly asynchronous.

There's no cut and dry way to detect whether you are in a synchronous or asynchronous context, but conveniently you usually don't care, you just care about the specific limits right now, and those are easy to get programmatically with the [Apex Limits class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_limits.htm).

I put together a little demo Apex that helps show the Apex Limits that are enforced in various execution contexts (batch, future, queueable, etc):

https://github.com/open-force/context-detective

[image]